# Show that g(n) is O(g(n)) for each of the following

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation

> `2^(sqrt(log(n))` is `O(n(^4/3))`
>
> `n^(4/3)` is `O(n(log(n))^3)`
>
> `n(log(n))^3)` is `O(n^(log(n))`
>
> `n^(log(n))` is `O(2^n)`

I can do it for them when they have the same base; I can't figure it out when they don't have the same base--I know that these are all true.

Comment: For example, n^(4/3) = 2^(log(n)*4/3)   The second statement is not true - maybe you have some brackets in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take log on both sides, for each of them. This is permitted because log is a monotonically increasing function